# MVC/Ajax:How to abandon session or log out from the application when a certain page is navigated to with `JavaScript`?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, pushstate, asp.net-mvc-ajax, popstate

I have an MVC application and when clicking on the browser `Back` button, I'm able to navigate in browser history.

I have the following MVC code to build the links:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Page1", "Index","Page1",new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId= "mainAjax", LoadingElementId="loader", OnComplete="ChangeUrl('Page1');" })
@Ajax.ActionLink("Page2", "Index", "Page2", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "mainAjax", LoadingElementId = "loader", OnComplete = "ChangeUrl('Page2');" })
@Ajax.ActionLink("Page3", "Index", "Page3", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "mainAjax", LoadingElementId = "loader", OnComplete = "ChangeUrl('Page3');" })
@Ajax.ActionLink("Page4", "Index", "Page4", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "mainAjax", LoadingElementId = "loader", OnComplete = "ChangeUrl('Page4');" })
```

And this is a `JavaScript` to handle the going back in the history:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

      $(window).bind('popstate', function () {
          window.location.href = window.location.href;
      });
});

function ChangeUrl(url)
{
    document.title = $('.pageTitle').text() + ' - eSite'
    window.history.pushState(null, null, url);

}
```

However, when going back to `login` page, once I click `Forward` button, I'm able to get back to the application without being authenticated.

What can I do, so the user's is signed out and his session is abandoned when browser's history is back to `Login` page?